# Issue With Spring repository wrong servlet-api.jar downloaded

Tags: java, spring, maven, servlets, repository

I have added below repository in my project **pom.xml** file

```
 <repository>
            <id>spring-milestone</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
 </repository>
```

But My project using **Servlet3.0** but when i am doing

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

its downloading servlet jar from this link

[Servlet API](http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone/javax/servlet/servlet-api/2.3/servlet-api-2.3.jar)

And my project referring **servlet-api2.3.jar** in Java build path and my project not working due to this

Because i used

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext
                .getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
            request.login(username, password);
```

and now i am getting compilation issue

> The method login(String, String) is undefined for the type
>   HttpServletRequest

Can any on tell why its showing old servlet-api.jar file can any one tell me how to fix it?

**EDIT :-**pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.ccc</groupId>
    <artifactId>3c</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>3c Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring.version>

    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>Prime Repo</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestone</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype-oss-public</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>terracotta-releases</id>
            <url>http://www.terracotta.org/download/reflector/releases</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>internal</id>
            <name>Archiva Managed Internal Repository</name>
            <url>http://myip:8888/repository/internal/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>java.net2</id>
            <name>Repository hosting the jee6 artifacts</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
        </repository>

    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSF -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- EL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- c3p0 dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.30</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jt400</groupId>
            <artifactId>jt400-full</artifactId>
            <version>5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ocpsoft</groupId>
            <artifactId>prettyfaces-jsf2</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.5-rc1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>twitter4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.facebook4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>facebook4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.facebookapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>facebook-java-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5</version>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.ehcache-spring-annotations</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache-spring-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scribe</groupId>
            <artifactId>scribe</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>

            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.5-beta5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Java port of the twitter-text handling libraries.https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.twitter</groupId>
            <artifactId>twitter-text</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version> <!-- or whatever the latest version is -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version> <!-- Or 2.0-SNAPSHOT -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JForum Jar -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.james</groupId>
            <artifactId>apache-mime4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.james</groupId>
            <artifactId>apache-mime4j-dom</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm-debug-all</artifactId>
            <version>4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15</artifactId>
            <version>1.45</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcmail-jdk15</artifactId>
            <version>1.45</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.l3s.boilerpipe</groupId>
            <artifactId>boilerpipe</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.beanshell</groupId>
            <artifactId>bsh</artifactId>
            <version>2.0b5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache-jgroupsreplication</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>fontbox</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.htmlparser</groupId>
            <artifactId>htmllexer</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.htmlparser</groupId>
            <artifactId>htmlparser</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.mp4parser</groupId>
            <artifactId>isoparser</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-RC-1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta-regexp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta-regexp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.cache</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbosscache-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.7.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-common-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.19.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging-spi</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.javaee</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.octo.captcha</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcaptcha</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.octo.captcha</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcaptcha-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>jempbox</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jgroups</groupId>
            <artifactId>jgroups</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.juniversalchardet</groupId>
            <artifactId>juniversalchardet</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-analyzers</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-highlighter</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-queries</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-memory</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>mchange-commons-java</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.drewnoakes</groupId>
            <artifactId>metadata-extractor</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.ucar</groupId>
            <artifactId>netcdf</artifactId>
            <version>4.2-min</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>rome</groupId>
            <artifactId>rome</artifactId>
            <version>0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>tagsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.gagravarr</groupId>
            <artifactId>vorbis-java-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.gagravarr</groupId>
            <artifactId>vorbis-java-tika</artifactId>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.03</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.xmp</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmpcore</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.tukaani</groupId>
            <artifactId>xz</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.jbosscaches</groupId> <artifactId>jbosscache-core</artifactId> 
            <version>3.2.7.GA</version> <scope>system</scope> <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/jbosscache-core-3.2.7.GA.jar</systemPath> 
            </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.jbosscaches</groupId> <artifactId>jboss-logging-spi</artifactId> 
            <version>2.1.2.GA</version> <scope>system</scope> <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/jboss-logging-spi-2.1.2.GA.jar</systemPath> 
            </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.jbosscaches</groupId> <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api</artifactId> 
            <version>1.0.1.GA</version> <scope>system</scope> <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/jboss-transaction-api-1.0.1.GA.jar</systemPath> 
            </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.vorbis</groupId> <artifactId>vorbis-java-core</artifactId> 
            <version>0.1-tests</version> <scope>system</scope> <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/vorbis-java-core-0.1-tests.jar</systemPath> 
            </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.imaging</groupId> <artifactId>imaging</artifactId> 
            <version>01012005</version> <scope>system</scope> <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/imaging-01012005.jar</systemPath> 
            </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.forum</groupId> <artifactId>jforum</artifactId> 
            <version>2.3.5</version> <scope>system</scope> <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/jforum-2.3.5.jar</systemPath> 
            </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jbosscaches</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-common-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.19.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.forum</groupId>
            <artifactId>jforum</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.imaging</groupId>
            <artifactId>imaging</artifactId>
            <version>01012005</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jbosscaches</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging-spi</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jbosscaches</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jbosscaches</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbosscache-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.7.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vorbis</groupId>
            <artifactId>vorbis-java-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.1-tests</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>3c</finalName>

    </build>



</project>
```

**Edit2:-**

```
[INFO] com.ccc:3c:war:1.0.0
[INFO] \- com.octo.captcha:jcaptcha:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO]    \- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.3:compile
```

Comment: you sure this version contains this method ? if yes you sure you are using this version `mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes="javax.servlet:servlet-api"`

Comment: No this method is from servlet-api3.0 but pom downloading servlet-api2.3.jar which creating issue

Comment: It would help if you post your pom's dependency and .m2/settings.xml.

Comment: post your `mvn help:effective-pom`

Comment: can you also post the output of `mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes="javax.servlet:servlet-api`

Comment: Its not showing anything i mean not creating  any tree

Comment: Ok look like something missing in your command `mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes="javax.servlet:servlet-api"`

Comment: @JigarJoshi added output will it is giving some detail about the issue?  
 
Ok Jcaptcha downloading servlet-api2.3.jar

Comment: Anyhow i want this jar should not be used can you tell me how to work in this situation project needs servlet3.0 while Jcaptcha using servlet-1pi-2.3.jar file?

Comment: You're not using the latest version of PDFBox, which is 1.8.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

exclude `javax.servlet:servlet-api` from `jcaptcha` dependency, jcaptcha should be able to work with `3.0`

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.octo.captcha</groupId>
  <artifactId>jcaptcha</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion> 
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions> 
</dependency>
```

Comment: any idea about tomcat+domain mapping?

Comment: post a new question with detail

Comment: added a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24873480/servlet3-login-issue-with-production-server

Comment: did u check my last question?