# Servlet3 login via local data source realm works in Tomcat 7.0.29, but fails in 7.0.54 & higher vesion

Tags: tomcat, servlets

I have issued servlet3.0 login and used below code like that

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext
                .getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
request.login(username, password);
```

and in **META-INF** folder added a **context.xml** file and added these thing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/3c">
                <Realm localDataSource="true" debug="99"
                className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm" connectionName="hariom"
                connectionPassword="password" connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://serverip:3306/ ccc" digest="md5" driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" roleNameCol="umul_role_name"
                userCredCol="umul_password" userNameCol="umul_email_id"
                userRoleTable="um_users_list" userTable="um_users_list" />
</Context>
```

and this is working fine in my local computer but when deploying same code in production server login not working even no any exception tomcat log file as well ..Anyone how to check what the issue why login is not working?

Here is **servlet3** entry in **pom.xml** file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**EDIT:**

Same Servlet3 login worked when i deployed my project into **apache-tomcat-7.0.29** but not worked with  **apache-tomcat-7.0.54**

**EDIT2:-**

Not worked with **apache-tomcat-8.0.9** as well

Comment: it is almost not possible to answer this question with provided information _no any exception tomcat log file as well_

Comment: I just put SOP in my code and found it showed  `javax.servlet.ServletException Login Failed` not more than this ...And one more thing when i am running poject from eclipse login working but when deploy in tomcat its throwing this exception..Even i replaced tomcat default `servlet.jar` from `javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar`

Comment: @JigarJoshi Another point i tested application with `apache-tomcat-7.0.29` it worked no change in tomcat lib folder now same application login not worked with `apache-tomcat-7.0.54`

Answer (score 0):

I would compare configuration files and jar-libraries between your Tomcats: the one in the Eclipse and the one you have the problem with.

A chance is that the Tomcat you are deploying to just misses MySql JDBC library.

But anyway it would be easier if you scan the Tomcat's log file for any exceptions (also with caused exceptions).